# Do Not Redirect for missing Folders

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, directory

I have a website which is basically a book (it is connected to a database). Users are able to read chapters for ex: http://examplebook.com/20. The problem I have is that I do not want to create folders for all the chapters in the book, but rather extract the chapter number from the url and just connect to database and display the book pages. If I do not have a folder for each chapter it just redirects and shows not found. I see some websites that have this feature so I am assuming it is possible. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Kind Regards,

Chewy.

Comment: Where do you want it to redirect to?

Comment: I simply do not want it to redirect anywhere, I want it to display the index.php, for example if you visit http://example.com/54 (and the 54 folder is not there) it will just display a 404 message, but I don't want it to display a 404 message. Sorry for not being clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]
```

That being in the htaccess file in your document root.

Comment: Well yes that's how I want it, but I want also the chapter number to stay for example if I go to http://example.com/20, it should not redirect anywhere and have that number in the link as well, so I can extract the 20 from it and connect it to the database to display chapter 20. The only thing I want to do is not create a folder for each chapter. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Chewy That's what that does, it does not change what's in the browser's address bar (unless PHP is redirecting).

Comment: Thanks this is perfect!! Sorry, I had a redirect code in index.php so it would redirect to chapter 1.. Thanks a lot!! :)